# change version postgres 9.5 to 9.3 (start)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have two version of postgres install

```
pg_lsclusters

9.3 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
9.5 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
```

I need start just 9.3 how do I do that?

Comment: amazon - Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-134-generic x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql@9.5-main.service
sudo systemctl start postgresql@9.3-main.service
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you [edit] and add some explanation to the answer.